# How do you attach a camera to a spawned player in unity 2d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, procedural-generation

So I'm working on a simple platformer in unity 2d. I created a level generator that generates random terrain, enemies, and player character right at the start of the level. I want to have the camera follow the player character. I tried using the SetParent()  method to set the player character as a child of the Main Camera. I got this error message: "Setting the parent of a transform which resides in a Prefab Asset is disabled to prevent data corruption." Is there a way to get around this? Or is there another way I could get my main camera to follow a spawned player character?

Here's the player character spawn potion of my level generator:

```
                if (x == 1)
                    {
                        Instantiate(player, new Vector3Int(x, y + 2, 0), Quaternion.identity);
                        player.transform.SetParent(MainCamera);
                    }
```

Any assistance would be most appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefabs have no parent, which is why you are getting that problem.

Modifying `player` is modifying a prefab. However, you mean to modify the instance made from that prefab. You need to get the result of `Instantiate` and modify that.

You probably also want to save it for reference later, so adding a field for that is appropriate.

Altogether:

```
private GameObject playerInstance; 

// ...  

playerInstance = Instantiate(player, new Vector3Int(x, y + 2, 0), Quaternion.identity); 
playerInstance.transform.SetParent(MainCamera.transform);
```

Or, if you'd like to make the camera a child of your player so that it follows the player automatically. If doing this, you probably also want to set the `worldPositionStays` parameter of `SetParent` to be false, so that the camera keeps its local position when the parent is set.

```
private GameObject playerInstance; 

// ...  

playerInstance = Instantiate(player, new Vector3Int(x, y + 2, 0), Quaternion.identity); 
mainCamera.transform.SetParent(playerInstance.transform, false);
```

Comment: Thanks!!! This worked perfectly!! I just had to add .transform to playerinstance when using your second method and it worked better without the worldPositionStays parameter (when I had false in there the camera was just solid background color). Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try directly assigning the parent as an instance of your prefab, then zero'ing the Camera's local transform:

```
GameObject myPlayer = Instantiate(player, new Vector3Int(x, y + 2, 0), Quaternion.identity); //GameObject can be whatever object type player is
myPlayer.transform.parent = MainCamera.transform;
MainCamera.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
```

Comment: `player` is still a prefab, this answer doesn't fix that.